# Force Numeric Keyboard for Mobile Device

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

This is not a "mobile" website.  It is regular HTML/CSS.  Is there a way I can force mobile devices to popup with the numeric keyboard when they focus on my textboxes?

Comment: There isn't a guaranteed way that will work on ALL devices. Do you have a specific issue you're trying to address? or do you just want an easy way for users to enter a number?

Comment: No specific issue, I'd just like it to default to the numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 18):

We've had the best luck with using a combination of `type="number"` and `pattern="\d*"`. We've seen success on iOS and Android devices, although I don't have a list of OS versions to share here.

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*" name="year">
```

Answer (score 9):

Just updating this post based on new tech..

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Works on most OS's aside from iOS.

So a newer version was introduced where you could simply use:

```
<input type="tel"/>
```

This forces a numbered keypad on any mobile device these days.

You can reference [here](http://mobileinputtypes.com/) for more info on this exact topic.

Answer (score 5):

Its called "-wap-input-format".
You can use it in your css or in style element such as

```
<input type="text" style="-wap-input-format: 'N'"/>
```

See http://www.developershome.com/wap/wcss/wcss_tutorial.asp?page=inputExtension2

**Edit:** I didn't realize you wanted to pop-up numeric keyboard. I'm not sure if it is possible

Comment: This is for WCSS, which I'm not using.  This does not work for regular CSS.

Comment: you should be able to use it inline style and if phone supports it, it will work. Works on symbian. http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?34533-Wap-CSS-support-in-XHTML-browsers

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a new input type "number" that tells mobile devices to bring up the numeric keypad:

`<input type="number"/>`

Read about it (and the other new input types) here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was searching for the answer and here is the updated version that should work now.

There is an option to additionally add this to your input:

```
inputmode="numeric"
```

So it will be like this:

```
<input inputmode="numeric" type="number"/>
```